# Cannot convert void to int[] and must have return type

Tags: c#

I've written a piece of code but there are errors with it and I can't figure out how to fix them since I'm still new to programming.

```
    static public int prodtab(int[] base1)
    {
        int output = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < base1.Length; i++)
        {
            output *= base1[i];
        }
        return output;
    }
    static public void annuletab(int[] base1, int pos1, int pos2)
    {
        base1 = base1.Where((nimporte, i) => i < pos1 || i > pos2).ToArray();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entrez la premiere position");
        position1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Entrez la deuxieme position");
        position2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] newvec = annuletab(vec, position1, position2);
```

Can someone figure what the error is?

Comment: `annuletab` returns `void`, and you're trying to assign it to `int[]`. Error message is pretty clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to programming!

As written `annuletab` does not return anything. Try this:

```
static public int[] annuletab(int[] base1, int pos1, int pos2)
{
    var base2 = base1.Where((nimporte, i) => i < pos1 || i > pos2).ToArray();
    return base2;
}
```